# realm response status = 400

Tags: java, android, permissions, realm

I'm trying to share a realm between users for a proof-of-concept messaging app on Android.

I have a realm with access url: `realm://192.168.1.90:9080/lynxenger/contacts`, the realm exists and has one register, but when I try to change it's permissions using an admin user that created the realm, I get the following on the log:

```
E/REALM_SYNC: Connection[2]: HTTP: Failed to switch protocols (response status = 400)
```

[Here's a Gist with the code](https://gist.github.com/apexJCL/db57d140c573d311131cc33050113c3f) I use to change permissions and update some data

#### EDIT:

There seems to be an error happening at server-side, here's the log file when the error occurs:

```
[proxy] internal error. Code undefined, status: undefined, message: SyntaxError: Unexpected token j in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at ProxyService.webSocketUpgradeHandler (/usr/lib/nodejs/realm-object-server-developer/.build/src/node/services/proxy.js:104:30)
    at ProxyService.safeUpgrade (/usr/lib/nodejs/realm-object-server-developer/.build/src/node/services/proxy.js:78:12)
    at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at onParserExecuteCommon (_http_server.js:411:14)
    at HTTPParser.onParserExecute (_http_server.js:379:5)
```

#### EDIT 2:

[Here's a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3yjvxJNV) with the android log

Comment: The syntax error in JSON doesn't sound good. Could you add logging to your Android client (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#logging) and post the log? Also, please create an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/202